# Play and Pause all embedded videos button doesn’t function after a refresh

Tags: javascript

I've created a website that allows users to display multiple YouTube videos, and I'm trying to buttons that pause and play every video by using JS.

The website functions correctly until the page is refreshed. Once the page is refreshed, the display button outputs empty divs rather than a video until the 3rd attempt. Meanwhile, the play and pause buttons only work after the display button is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let input = document.getElementById("video-url");
  let displayButton = document.getElementById("display-video");
  let containerDiv = document.getElementById("video-container");
  let stateList = [];
  let player;
  let players = [];


    // Load the YT library
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    displayButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      let videoID = input.value.split("watch?v=")[1];
      let innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
      innerDiv.className = "inner";
      innerDiv.id = "video-" + players.length;
      let outerDiv = document.createElement("div");
      outerDiv.className = "window draggable resizable";
      outerDiv.style.transform = "translate3d(100px, 100px, 0)";
      outerDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
      init();
      containerDiv.appendChild(outerDiv);
    
      player = new YT.Player("video-" + players.length, {
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        videoId: videoID,
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
      });
      players.push(player);

      init();
      saveState();

    });
    
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
      let playButton = document.getElementById("play-button");
      playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        event.target.playVideo();
      });
      
      let pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause-button");
      pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        event.target.pauseVideo();
      });
  
      let stopButton = document.getElementById("stop-button");
      stopButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        event.target.stopVideo();
      });
    }

  function init() {
    // the ui-resizable-handles are added here
    $('.resizable').resizable();
    // makes GSAP Draggable avoid clicks on the resize handles
    $('.ui-resizable-handle').attr('data-clickable', true);
    // make the element draggable
    Draggable.create('.draggable', {
      onPress: function () {
        $(this.target).addClass('ui-resizable-resizing');
      },
      onRelease: function() {
        $(this.target).removeClass('ui-resizable-resizing');
        saveState();
      }
    });
    $('.resizable').dblclick(function () {
      var win = $(this);
      toggleSize(win);
      saveState();
    });
  }
  
  function createHandleBar() {
    // create handlebar
    let handleBar = document.createElement('div');
    handleBar.className = 'handleBar';
    $(handleBar).css({
      position: 'absolute',
      top: '0px',
      width: '100%', height: '43px',
      padding: '4px',
      boxSizing: 'border-box'
    });
    saveState();
    return handleBar;
}

function saveState() {
  let state = {
    id: stateList.length,
    state: containerDiv.innerHTML
  };
  stateList.push(state);
  window.localStorage.setItem('videoState', JSON.stringify(stateList));
  window.history.pushState({}, '', '#' + btoa(JSON.stringify(stateList)));
}

if (window.location.hash) {
  let stateListFromStorage = JSON.parse(atob(window.location.hash.substring(1)));
  let stateToRestore = stateListFromStorage[stateListFromStorage.length - 1];
  containerDiv.innerHTML = stateToRestore.state;
  init();
}
});
```

GitHub Code: https://github.com/RyanOliverV/Video_Viewer

Page: https://ryanoliverv.github.io/Video_Viewer/

Comment: First, did you check which of this code gets properly exeucted? e.g. with `console.log` or a debugger in the browser dev tools? Might be useful debugging information

Comment: Why are you waiting for the `load` event?Afaik, if the iframe already finished loading before you attach the listener, this won't be called (as it does not finish loading after you add the event listener)

Comment: I tried waiting to load as an attempt of fixing the issue, but it didn't help.

Comment: The code seems to be logging the correct outputs to the console (I think), I've added the results to the main post

Comment: Okay so after debugging with console.log, it appears `iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');` is logging as undefined

Comment: It's expected that [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#return_value) returns undefined, that shouldn't be the problem

Comment: Is it caused by the fact I haven’t used the YouTube iframe API?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with YouTube iframes. To me everything you did looks right and the general debugging tricks didn't help, so I won't be able to help you further

Comment: Update: I'm now using the Youtube API and the play/pause buttons work, but they stop working after refreshing the page.